# $k[t]$ is finitely generated $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ -module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading example 3, section 7.3 of vakil's notes. It says that $k[t]$ is a finitely generated $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ -module by 1,t. This really confuses me. And he also claim $D(t^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $D(x)$, I also can not see this. Could some one help me? Thanks! I apologize if this question is too elementary.

Comment: May I ask what is vanilla's notes? Thanks.

Comment: @YifanWu I am so sorry, it should be Vakil.... I have corrected it.

Comment: What is $t$? Please don't expect people to look for vakil's notes. Instead, give enough information in the question for it to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what is $t$. May be you mean the following. Consider the map (which is an inclusion) $R=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)\to k[t]$ given by $x\mapsto t^2-1, y\mapsto t(t^2-1)$. Then $k[t]$ is a generated by $1,t$ as a module over $R$. The rest should be clear. You can see that $k[t]$ is just the integral closure of $R$.